# how to retrieve an attribute value in ternary operator?

Tags: lightning

i have two attributes in my component:

```
<aura:attribute name="sObjectName" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="acc" type="Account" />
```

the attribute sObjectName contains the sObjectName (Lead, Account, Contact etc)
the attribute acc contains an Id,Name,Type.

when i write this line

```
<label>{!v.acc.Id}</label>
```

i receive the id of the account and it works great

when i write this line:

```
<label>{!v.sObjectName=='Lead' ? 'txtTest' : !v.acc.Id}</label>
```

when im in the lead record, it print 'txtTest' just fine, but when i'm not - it prints 'false' and not !v.acc.Id

what am i doing wrong? what is the correct syntax? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that you are getting false is that the `v.acc.Id` is a javascript string, and the logical negation operator, `!`, returns false when applied to strings.

```
var s = 'string'; 
console.log(s);   // string
console.log(!s);  // false
```

Basically, all you need to do is remove the `!`:

```
<label>{!v.sObjectName=='Lead' ? 'txtTest' : v.acc.Id}</label>
```

Comment: so why did it work when i wrote '<label>{!v.acc.Id}</label>' ? @martin

Comment: The first `!` is part of merge syntax `{!  }`, additional exclamation points are taken as part of the inner expression.

Comment: Minor quibble - `!` will return `true` when applied to a null or empty Javascript string.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian good point the empty string is a falsy value.